# How to $_GET value from string

Tags: php

This is my string

```
component/content/article?id=9
```

How to get dynamicly get 9 from it?

I want to do it on string, not url, and there can be a case when there is more paremateres, like in url.
I want to do exacly the same like $_GET, but on string

**reworded question (by Ayesh K):**

I have a string that contains a URL path and a query string. I want to parse the query string to an array of keys and value as if it was current page's query string so I can get them from `$_GET`.

For example, I have the following string:

```
component/content/article?id=9
```

Now I want to get the `id` value (`9`) from an array. How do I parse such string to separate the query string and turn it into an array ?

Comment: Really ? please try to search a bit by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the answers here are not using the specific tools built for that.

You can use the following to parse a URL or path string and get the desired value as if it was in $_GET.

```
<?php
  $str = 'component/content/article?id=9';
  $query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY); // Get the string part after the "?"
  parse_str($query, $params); // Parse the string. This is the SAME mechanism how php uses to parse $_GET.
  print $params['id'];
?>
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/ki00i

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I see you updated your code.

This is a more robust way to parse a URL string:

```
$string = 'component/content/article?q=1&item[]=345&item[]=522';

// parse the url into its components
$url_parts = parse_url($string);

// parse the query components to get the variables
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $get_vars);

echo $get_vars['q'];
echo $get_vars['item'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $gets = array();
   $string = "component/content/article?id=9&sid=15";
   $parts = explode('?',$string);
   $parts = explode('&',$parts[1]);
   foreach($parts as $part){
      $part = explode('=',$part);
      $gets[$part[0]] = $part[1];
   }
   print_r($gets); // array('id' => '9','sid' => '15');
?>
```

Comment: not working, returning chars

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. Also, this fails if the URL contains array format (`example.com/?q=1&item[]=345&item[]=522`).

Comment: forgot to add '=' explode, fixed